# add dynamic class to ul li with set interval timing

Tags: jquery

```
function addcls() {
        $('#slider ul li.current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('current');
    };

 setInterval(function () {
        addcls();
       }, 3000);
```

the above code removing 'current' class from first li tag but not inserting to the next li tag. how to achieve this with set interval

html

```
<ul>
        <li class="current">SLIDE 1</li>
    <li class="" style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
    <li class="">SLIDE 3</li>
    <li class="" style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: $(this) makes no sense in that function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(this)` makes no sense in your function, does it?

```
function addcls() {
        var current = $('#slider ul li.current').removeClass('current'),
            next = current.next().length ? current.next() : current.siblings().filter(':first');
        next.addClass('current');
    };

 setInterval(function () {
        addcls();
       }, 3000);
```

Comment: you could also write next = current.next() || current.siblings().filter(':first');

Comment: +1 but to follow your comment, `current.next()` will always be evaluated as truly

Answer (score 1):

[.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
function addcls() {
        var $this = $('#slider ul li.current').removeClass('current');
        $this.next('li').addClass('current');
    };
```

---

If you want to loop through

```
function addcls() {
    var $this =$('#slider ul li.current').removeClass('current');
    if ($this.next('li').length > 0) { //if next element is there 
        $this.next('li').addClass('current'); //add class to next to next element 
    } else { 
        $this.closest('ul').find('li:eq(0)').addClass('current'); //else add class to 1 st element 
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**[closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)** traverse up the DOM tree and get the first matched ancestor.

Your list items is the siblings of each other so you can use **[siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** instead:

```
$(this).siblings('li').addClass('current');
```